# Service external IP pending on kubernetes hosted on jelastic

Tags: kubernetes, ip, jelastic

I have installed my kubernetes cluster on Jelastic. Now, I tried to define a service of `LoadBalancer` type and would like it to be provided with an external IP. The external IP is currently marked as `pending`. What should I do to make it non-pending? Do I have to provide the worker nodes with an external IPv4?

In my current setup, my worker nodes have no IPv4 because I put an nginx load-balancer in front of the cluster:

[image]

The IPv4 is set on the nginx node. Is that a problem? If I want to access my loadbalancer service inside of my kubernetes cluster, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For `LoadBalancer` service type to work, the cloud provider must implemenet the relevant APIs to get it to work.

With regard to `Jelastic`, as per their docs, they don't support it https://docs.jelastic.com/kubernetes-exposing-services/:

> Jelastic PaaS does not support the LocaBalancer service type currently.

Answer (score 1):

In Jelastic Public IP addresses have to be attached to worker nodes.
Every worker node has ingress controller instance running (based oт nginx/haproxy/traefik) with http/https listeners that can forward traffic to the  required service.

You have just to bind your domain as [CNAME to Environment FQDN](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-domains/) and every your worker node can accept requests in RR-DNS mode.
Does this scenario works for you or you have a specific requirement to use external load balancer?

By default, when Public IPs are not attached to worker instances the traffic is going through the [Shared Load Balancer](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-domains/).

P.S. If you install Certification Manager Addon to your K8s cluster - you can also issue free Let's Encrypt certificates.

Comment: Well, currently the motivation behind the frontal nginx is that an IPv4 costs me money, and if I have 3 worker nodes, I pay for 3 IPv4, whereas I pay only for one IPv4 with the frontal nginx load-balancer. Also I configured my cluster 2 years ago and at that time it was not easy to configure SSL on the cluster (cf. e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/kubernetes/issues/27)). Based on the advice provided in that issue, I've gone for the frontal load-balancer. How is it looking now? from your reply, I gather the issue has been solved. Where is that documented?